# Javascript function skips navigator.clipboard.writeText and just does window.open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following function:

```
function openurl(){
navigator.clipboard.writeText("TextToCopy");
window.open('url');
}
```

executing in this:

```
<button onclick=openurl()>Openurlbutton</button>
```

It only opens the window and does not copy the text.
I am so lost.. help :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText .. writeText() returns a promise that you need to resolve doing: `.then(function(){/*nextstep*/})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigator.clipboard.writeText is an async function. For you to work you can edit your code to the following. (https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api)

```
 async function openurl() {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText('TextToCopy');
      window.open('url');
    }
```