# Clipboard API copy to clipboard and then open new window? Avoid loosing window focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, html5-clipboard-api

Is it possible to open a new browser tab after content has been copied into the clipboard?

Currently I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.` which I take it that I can't open a new window within the function as I know the tab has to be active for copy to clipboard to work (without permissions).
https://web.dev/async-clipboard/

Do I need to run the code outside the function somehow ie. event or observer to detect when copyToClipboard function has been executed? Or any other way to run it in the function and ensure writing to clipboard is finished before the new window opens? (I tried even setTimeout to no avail).

HTML

```
<body>
<button type=button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
<div id="template">
  Test
</div>
</body>
```

Js

```
function copyToClipboard(){
    try {
      const htmlCode = template.innerHTML;
      const blobInput = new Blob([htmlCode], { type: 'text/html' })
      navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blobInput })])
      alert('Copied')

var win = window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/', '_blank');
  if (win) {
      //Browser has allowed it to be opened
      win.focus();
  } else {
      //Browser has blocked it
      alert('Please allow popups for this website');
  }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e)
    }
  };
```

I also tried using .then after navigator with same issue

```
navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blobInput })]).then( window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/', '_blank') );
```

**UPDATE**

Found out I need to use  async and await, that worked!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990164/8719001

```
async function openurl() {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText('TextToCopy');
      window.open('url');
    }
```